# How can I call node indexjs which is outside of /src folder in MERN app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, mern

I am about to finish my first app(mern). I had a problem with getting data from mongoDB to my Autocomplete search-bar. I did find a tutorial(nodejs+express only tho) which shows how can I actually get data from database, I did follow it 1:1 but as I wrote before, its only nodejs+express. I did create it in folder 'routes' which is outside of /src folder and I dont know how can I call it out to check if it even works. 
Here is how it looks like, I hope it works:
[image]

And this is the component I want to use the data which I've potentially got from database. Its hardcoded for now.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to run your Express application locally then call your endpoint like you would any API.

It might be helpful if you move this in to its own folder

Project
--- Front end 
--- Backend

Comment: This should be a comment, but you posted as an answer.

Comment: @urqpdykx is it the only way to do it?